# Change Shipment Email Name in Magento Commerce

Tags: magento

Does anyone know where the file that controls shipment email when clicking "send tracking information" button on order section of Magento Commerce Admin (Admin -> Sales -> Shipment) is located?

I want to change the sender name in that file.  I have tried to modify the sender options in Salesemail -> Shipment, but it does not take effect.  The mail is always sending in a particular sender name.  How can I change this sender name?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the sender name when sending shipment mail to customer also from admin side that is : **System->configuration->Sales -> sales Email->Shipment**. Then select Shipment Email Sender.This sender name can be change from Store Email Addresses in **admin->configuration->General->Store Email Addresses**.Under that click the which you have selected on sales email and type sender name..